# How to loop through an table and turn rows into objects using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, loops

I want to use nokogiri to loop through a html and create an object corresponding to every row. I am able to define the root xpaths where I want the data  to fill the object varibles comes from but I dont know how to group these as an object.

My code is below. I know it doesn't work but I dont know what direction to go to make it work.

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
  "
    
    
      
      
          LV1LV2LV3
      
      
          MV1MV2MV3
      
            
          NV1NV2NV3
      
      
      
      
      "
HTML_END

class Post
     def initialize(v1, v2, v3 )
            @v1 =v1
            @v2 = v2
            @v3  = v3
      end

```
  def v1= (v1)
    @v1 =v1
  end

  def v2
    @v2 =v2
  end

  def v3
    @v3 =v3
  end
```

end

class PostList
        def initialize
          @posts = Array.new
        end

```
    def append(aPost)
      @posts.push(aPost)
      self
    end

    def deleteFirst
      @posts.shift
    end

    def deleteLast
      @posts.pop
    end
```

end

list = PostList.new

parent = doc.css('body').first

## gets the contects of the row

parent.xpath("//div/table[@class='ipbtable']/tr" ).each do |a_tag|

k1 = "x"
k2 =  "x"
k3 = "x"

a_tag.xpath("td[1]").each do |x_tag|

puts x_tag.content

end

list.append(Post.new(k1, k2, k3)   )

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with the code appears to be you're passing strings (`'K1', 'K2', 'K3'`) that vaguely resemble the names of variables rather than the variables themselves (`k1, k2, k3`). However, you could express this more succinctly as:

```
doc.search('table > tr').each do |row|
  properties = row.search('td/text()').collect {|text| text.to_s}
  list.append Post.new(*properties)
end
```

This simply loops over each row and creates a Post using the textual content of each td in the row.